# while executing following command, why am I getting permission denied? I am trying to run this on HDP

Tags: linux, permissions, ipython

I installed Jupyter on Hortonworks Sandbox and wanted to run jupyter using port forwarding.

I followed these steps : https://hortonworks.com/hadoop-tutorial/using-ipython-notebook-with-apache-spark/

I am not able to start Jupyter using

./start_ipython_notebook.sh

I tried /root/start_ipython_notebook.sh but getting permission denied.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You probably should be running that as the root user if that's where the file exists. Not a hadoop problem, it's a basic Linux permissions issue

Answer (score 0):

run `ls -la` in that directory what does it output?
You will probably see that the file you are trying to run doesn't allow your `amar` user to run it.

To solve this, either install jupyter in another directory where it has the correct user rights. Or use the `chown` and `chmod` to give you the correct rights over those files inorder to run them.